# How can i save float32array data into mongodb?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

i try to save a float32array datatype of Descriptors used in  [face-api.js tutorial](https://github.com/justadudewhohacks/face-api.js/) into mongodb, which creats error as follows:

```
Error [ValidationError]: Face validation failed: face1: Cast to Number failed for value "[
  '-0.07273564487695694',
  '0.06783964484930038',
  '0.017196351662278175',
  '-0.06767699867486954',
  '0.018848462030291557',
  '-0.008953484706580639',
  '-0.10941299051046371',
  '-0.08474595099687576',
  '0.18334418535232544',
  '-0.13277113437652588',
  '0.21881742775440216',
  '0.05348524823784828',
  '-0.1738838255405426',
  '-0.10882828384637833',
  '0.022012043744325638',
  '0.12650063633918762',
  '-0.1980297714471817',
  '-0.05259150266647339',
  '-0.1738252341747284',
  '-0.07430439442396164',
  '-0.00950242392718792',
  '0.016983192414045334',
  '0.14309418201446533',
  '0.007861343212425709',
  '-0.15108434855937958',
  '-0.3753374516963959',
  '-0.09251140058040619',
  '-0.15258368849754333',
  '0.018157916143536568',
  '-0.14218701422214508',
  '-0.09158512204885483',
  '-0.027028504759073257',
  '-0.18213948607444763',
  '-0.08395160734653473',
  '-0.01923770271241665',
  '-0.009705804288387299',
  '-0.016477856785058975',
  '-0.01471498142927885',
  '0.2132747620344162',
  '0.09748928248882294',
  '-0.12596380710601807',
  '0.09632328897714615',
  '-0.010693545453250408',
  '0.2434854358434677',
  '0.2999197244644165',
  '0.045587435364723206',
  '0.03161664679646492',
  '-0.05649133771657944',
  '0.15018106997013092',
  '-0.23106248676776886',
  '0.0143006332218647',
  '0.11923261731863022',
  '0.10614773631095886',
  '0.04596344381570816',
  '0.11038381606340408',
  '-0.1268938034772873',
  '-0.000030407682061195374',
  '0.0907360389828682',
  '-0.09167303889989853',
  '0.06623714417219162',
  '0.03635689243674278',
  '-0.08683675527572632',
  '-0.029647760093212128',
  '0.038635361939668655',
  '0.1835651397705078',
  '0.06123190000653267',
  '-0.13125522434711456',
  '-0.06574095040559769',
  '0.12370463460683823',
  '-0.024815889075398445',
  '0.03423560783267021',
  '-0.015258995816111565',
  '-0.16121728718280792',
  '-0.18937481939792633',
  '-0.2804066240787506',
  '0.035129714757204056',
  '0.2984723448753357',
  '0.12609252333641052',
  '-0.22052307426929474',
  '0.0007893451256677508',
  '-0.19253642857074738',
  '0.02280258946120739',
  '0.008555280975997448',
  '0.013857826590538025',
  '-0.07759181410074234',
  '-0.06886880099773407',
  '-0.08058007806539536',
  '0.027053244411945343',
  '0.13577044010162354',
  '-0.014992798678576946',
  '-0.0033843964338302612',
  '0.18782006204128265',
  '-0.03454151004552841',
  '0.03207124397158623',
  '0.021744150668382645',
  '0.06258267164230347',
  '-0.229567289352417',
  '-0.049789320677518845',
  '-0.15495271980762482',
  '-0.009344004094600677',
  ... 28 more items
]" at path "face1", face2: Cast to Number failed for value "[
  '-0.09841682761907578',   '0.10429154336452484',   '0.02155156247317791',
  '-0.0520382784307003',    '0.003075589891523123',  '0.02731766179203987',
  '-0.06316100805997849',   '-0.08978841453790665',  '0.17524316906929016',
  '-0.06021083891391754',   '0.20898853242397308',   '0.04531601443886757',
  '-0.2273748219013214',    '-0.13791939616203308',  '0.03461577743291855',
  '0.10593116283416748',    '-0.16997823119163513',  '-0.04051877558231354',
  '-0.1157040074467659',    '-0.13753467798233032',  '0.00451170327141881',
  '-0.0035286874044686556', '0.12593451142311096',   '0.03245891258120537',
  '-0.19241401553153992',   '-0.3184763491153717',   '-0.04043048247694969',
  '-0.17030549049377441',   '-0.0513293594121933',   '-0.08657143265008926',
  '-0.043777234852313995',  '0.012140932492911816',  '-0.1894371658563614',
  '-0.12472780793905258',   '0.0404059961438179',    '0.013797461055219173',
  '-0.0014847844140604138', '0.02460971660912037',   '0.20598173141479492',
  '0.01733708567917347',    '-0.10046811401844025',  '0.10734308511018753',
  '0.03710935637354851',    '0.23082618415355682',   '0.25308746099472046',
  '0.06004834920167923',    '-0.01260399166494608',  '-0.06998976320028305',
  '0.14949968457221985',    '-0.24164462089538574',  '0.048128850758075714',
  '0.1337026059627533',     '0.061368342489004135',  '0.02466494031250477',
  '0.0861603170633316',     '-0.15172605216503143',  '-0.0034477391745895147',
  '0.10432615131139755',    '-0.12314924597740173',  '0.037213362753391266',
  '0.02678604982793331',    '-0.09252163767814636',  '-0.07801863551139832',
  '0.03722367063164711',    '0.14181503653526306',   '0.11837714165449142',
  '-0.10465218871831894',   '-0.0963580384850502',   '0.12955503165721893',
  '-0.015165491960942745',  '0.0335954874753952',    '0.04591371864080429',
  '-0.17047487199306488',   '-0.200806125998497',    '-0.24049332737922668',
  '0.1046692430973053',     '0.3785543143749237',    '0.15583226084709167',
  '-0.1976466029882431',    '-0.016453050076961517', '-0.17181381583213806',
  '0.07842658460140228',    '0.07034406810998917',   '-0.011151890270411968',
  '-0.06393297761678696',   '-0.11788173764944077',  '-0.01764458790421486',
  '0.06571757048368454',    '0.0907316505908966',    '0.00919581949710846',
  '-0.06429607421159744',   '0.20871053636074066',   '0.0032271952368319035',
  '0.060321446508169174',   '0.026394570246338844',  '0.03664182126522064',
  '-0.14991241693496704',   '0.005795528646558523',  '-0.20117248594760895',
  '-0.01487714983522892',
  ... 28 more items
]"..............and so on
```

here is my database

```js
var faceSchema = mongoose.Schema({
   name: String,
   face1: Number,
   face2: Number,
   face3: Number
});

var Face = mongoose.model("Face", faceSchema);
```

here is when i save it to database

```js
app.post('/face_check',function (req, res){
  

   var faceInfo = req.body; //Get the parsed information
   console.log(faceInfo.name);
   console.log(faceInfo.face1);
   var newFace = new Face({
      name: faceInfo.name,
      face1: faceInfo.face1,
      face2: faceInfo.face2,
      face3: faceInfo.face3

   });
   
   newFace.save(function(err, Face){
      if(err)
         console.log(err);
      else
         console.log("success saveing face ino");
   });

      

   


});
```

which will get post from the following

```js
const singleResulto1 = await faceapi
      .detectSingleFace(input1)
      .withFaceLandmarks()
      .withFaceDescriptor()

      const singleResulto2 = await faceapi
      .detectSingleFace(input2)
      .withFaceLandmarks()
      .withFaceDescriptor()

      const singleResulto3 = await faceapi
      .detectSingleFace(input3)
      .withFaceLandmarks()
      .withFaceDescriptor()
        
        
$.post("/face_check", {
          name: username, 
          face1: singleResulto1.descriptor,
          face2: singleResulto2.descriptor,
          face3: singleResulto3.descriptor
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you were able to find the solution to this or no, but here is how I solved it. The main problem was that while storing the data into MongoDB, it was getting turned in **Object type** , therefore when you got the data from MongoDB, you were required to turn it into **Float32Array type**. This was the tricky part, because in order for the function to work, we first need to turn the **ObjectType** into Array and then into **Float32Array**.

To give some background understanding, here is how I defined my Schema -

```js
const faceSchema = new Schema({
    label:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
        unique:true
    },
    descriptions:{
        type:Object,
        required:true
    }
})
```

Now I think it's clear how I'm storing the data. The following code is where I upload the data to the DB, notice that I only store the descriptions -

```js
async function uploadLabeledImages(images, label) {

    const descriptions = [];
    // Loop through the images
    for (let i = 1; i < images.length; i++) {
      const img = await canvas.loadImage(images[i]);

      // Read each face and save the face descriptions in the descriptions array
      const detections = await faceapi.detectSingleFace(img).withFaceLandmarks().withFaceDescriptor();
      descriptions.push(detections.descriptor);
    }

    // Create a new face document with the given label and save it in DB
    const createFace = new Face({
      label: label,
      descriptions: descriptions,
    });
    await createFace.save();
    return true;
  
}
```

Next I will show how I got the data from the DB and how I converted it to Float32Array-

```js
async function LoadFaceMatcherFromDB() {
  // Get all the face data from mongodb and loop through each of them to read the data
  let faces = await Face.find();
  for (i = 0; i < faces.length; i++) {
    // Change the face data descriptors from Objects to Float32Array type
    for (j = 0; j < faces[i].descriptions.length; j++) {
    
    // Please pay attention to this part, this is where the magic happens
    // For each desciption Object stored in my DB I turn it into an Array then Float32Array
      faces[i].descriptions[j] = new Float32Array(Object.values(faces[i].descriptions[j]));
    
    
    }
    // Turn the DB face docs to Descriptors
    faces[i] = new faceapi.LabeledFaceDescriptors(faces[i].label, faces[i].descriptions);
  }

  // Load the models
  await faceapi.nets.faceRecognitionNet.loadFromDisk(reqPath + "/models/rec-model");
  await faceapi.nets.faceLandmark68Net.loadFromDisk(reqPath + "/models/rec-model");
  await faceapi.nets.ssdMobilenetv1.loadFromDisk(reqPath + "/models/rec-model");

  // Load face matcher to find the matching face
  const faceMatcher = new faceapi.FaceMatcher(faces, 0.6);
  return faceMatcher;
}
```

I hope this solves your problem. May the force be with those who visit this page.

Answer (score 0):

I am using face-api.js right now. Please try define your schema as following code.

```
const landMarkSchema = new Schema({
    _label:{
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    _descriptors:{
        type: [Object],
        required: true
    }
})
module.exports = mongoose.model('FaceLandmark',landMarkSchema,'face_landmark');
```

Comment: But descriptor is a Float32Array, MongoDB save it as Object type. So we need to using Float32Array methods to cast it